# How to set up Laravel Forge / nginx default site

Tags: nginx, laravel-forge

I have a nginx server with a single web site, managed by Laravel Forge.  At the moment it responds to requests for a single subdomain: subdomain_a.mydomain.com.au.  I need it to respond to requests for subdomain_b.mydomain.com.au, and also the raw IP address.  How do I do that?

Here's the nginx config:

```
# FORGE CONFIG (DO NOT REMOVE!)
include forge-conf/subdomain_a.mydomain.com.au/before/*;

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name subdomain_a.mydomain.com.au;
    root /home/forge/subdomain_a.mydomain.com.au/public;

    # FORGE SSL (DO NOT REMOVE!)
    # ssl_certificate;
    # ssl_certificate_key;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES256-(truncated by me!!!);
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparams.pem;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    # FORGE CONFIG (DO NOT REMOVE!)
    include forge-conf/subdomain_a.mydomain.com.au/server/*;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/subdomain_a.mydomain.com.au-error.log error;

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}

# FORGE CONFIG (DO NOT REMOVE!)
include forge-conf/subdomain_a.mydomain.com.au/after/*;
```

I am new to both nginx and Forge, and this is due to be in production within a few days.

Answer (score 0):

In forge open your website page, at the right bottom there is a dropup menu called "Files", click on "Edit Nginx configuration".

Now you have to change this directive (as described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options#Syntax)) from:

`add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";`

to

`add_header X-Frame-Options "allow from https://your-ip-or-domain.tld"`